# How to export methods to another module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have object extends from event:

```
var A = function () {
    EventEmitter.call(this);
};

inherits(A, EventEmitter);

var a = module.exports =  Object.create(new A());

A.prototype.method = module.exports = function f(arg1,arg2){}
```

On another module I make:

```
var controller = require('./filename');

function main(){
    controller.f(arg1,arg2);
}
```

I guess something with the require/export is wrong but I couldn't find what.

Comment: What's all this `inherits`, `prototype` and other voodoo you've got going on? Modules are cached so only one instance of their exports at at time, no?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var A = function() {
    EventEmitter.call(this);
};

inherits(A, EventEmitter);

var a = module.exports = new A();

A.prototype.f = function(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log("Hello, world!");
}
```

Your folly was to reassign `module.exports` a second type. This should do what you want; namely, the export of the module is an instance of `A`, such that `require('./controller')` returns the `A` instance, and you can call `f(arg1, arg2)` on that.

By the way, the `Object.create()` was extraneous.